# iOS app install animation using CSS3

Tags: ios, css, animation

I'm trying to develop a Javascript-based file uploader, for which I'm trying to recreate the same animation that iOS 7 uses for new app install:

[image: iOS app install animation]

Any ideas of how can I achieve this using CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a basic jQuery plugin with a similar effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/ideatic/KL69s/1/

To use it, simply call the plugin with the progress value as argument:

```
$('#element').loader(25);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found something in a different thread few weeks ago, it may be useful for your purpose.

[CSS Progress Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle)