# How to draw circular progress bar using javascript and css

Tags: javascript, css

I want draw a circular progress bar like the below image using CSS and JS.
Could you please help me with it

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.loader {
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="loader"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can animate SVG circles without much trouble. Take a look at the selected answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42234855/is-it-possible-to-draw-a-partial-circle-outline-in-css-open-ring-shape for some inspiration.

Comment: no it is not partial circle, based on the downloaded data inner circle will be drawn

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [link](https://codepen.io/jo-asakura/pen/stFHi) may be helpful. Also you can try this js library as well [Progressbar js](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/)

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700);
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  background: #ecf0f1;
  color: #444;
  font-family: 'Lato', Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
}
.set-size {
  font-size: 10em;
}
.charts-container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.pie-wrapper {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  float: left;
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.pie-wrapper:nth-child(3n+1) {
  clear: both;
}
.pie-wrapper .pie {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  clip: rect(0, 1em, 1em, 0.5em);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.pie-wrapper .pie .half-circle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.1em solid #3498db;
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0, 0.5em, 1em, 0);
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.pie-wrapper .label {
  background: #34495e;
  border-radius: 50%;
  bottom: 0.4em;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  cursor: default;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.25em;
  left: 0.4em;
  line-height: 2.6em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0.4em;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0.4em;
}
.pie-wrapper .label .smaller {
  color: #bdc3c7;
  font-size: .45em;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  vertical-align: super;
}
.pie-wrapper .shadow {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0.1em solid #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.pie-wrapper.style-2 .label {
  background: none;
  color: #7f8c8d;
}
.pie-wrapper.style-2 .label .smaller {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-30 .pie .right-side {
  display: none;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-30 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #3498db;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-30 .pie .left-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(108deg);
          transform: rotate(108deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-60 .pie {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-60 .pie .right-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-60 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #9b59b6;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-60 .pie .left-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(216deg);
          transform: rotate(216deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie .right-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #e67e22;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-90 .pie .left-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(324deg);
          transform: rotate(324deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-45 .pie .right-side {
  display: none;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-45 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #1abc9c;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-45 .pie .left-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(162deg);
          transform: rotate(162deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-75 .pie {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-75 .pie .right-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-75 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #8e44ad;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-75 .pie .left-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
          transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-95 .pie {
  clip: rect(auto, auto, auto, auto);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-95 .pie .right-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
          transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-95 .pie .half-circle {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}
.pie-wrapper.progress-95 .pie .left-side {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(342deg);
          transform: rotate(342deg);
}
.pie-wrapper--solid {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.pie-wrapper--solid:before {
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left;
          transform-origin: left;
}
.pie-wrapper--solid .label {
  background: transparent;
}
.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-65 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #e67e22 50%, #34495e 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e67e22 50%, #34495e 50%);
}
.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-65:before {
  background: #e67e22;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(126deg);
          transform: rotate(126deg);
}
.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-25 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #9b59b6 50%, #34495e 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #9b59b6 50%, #34495e 50%);
}
.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-25:before {
  background: #34495e;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-270deg);
          transform: rotate(-270deg);
}
.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-88 {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #3498db 50%, #34495e 50%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #3498db 50%, #34495e 50%);
}
.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-88:before {
  background: #3498db;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(43.2deg);
          transform: rotate(43.2deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="set-size charts-container">
  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-30">
    <span class="label">30<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-60">
    <span class="label">60<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-90">
    <span class="label">90<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-45 style-2">
    <span class="label">45<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-75 style-2">
    <span class="label">75<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="pie-wrapper progress-95 style-2">
    <span class="label">95<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
    <div class="pie">
      <div class="left-side half-circle"></div>
      <div class="right-side half-circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-65">
    <span class="label">65<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-25">
    <span class="label">25<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-88">
    <span class="label">88<span class="smaller">%</span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```