# Have bootstraps progress bar converted to circle and image inside it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to be able to use the bootstrap progress bar so that it can wrap around my image in a circle around the edge.

Like in the code below on html I still would prefer to set the width in the div the way bootstrap does.

> **Question:** How am I able to use bootstrap progress bar to be wrapped
>   around my image where would still be able to set progress bar with in div?

Here what I have tried so far.
Snippet [Example](http://codepen.io/riwakawebsitedesigns/pen/rLqQzy) Codepen

CSS

```
.progress {
    border-radius: 50%;
} 
.progress-bar {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.wrapper > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">Circle progress bar with image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">

            <div class="wrapper">

                <img src="holder.js/150x150" class="img-circle img-thumbnail" />  

                <div class="progress" style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">  
                    <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 50%"></div>  
                </div>  

            </div> 

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not bootstrap but take a look at http://codepen.io/geedmo/pen/InFfd

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Sorry, bad link pasted, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle can give you ideas about how to do it...

Comment: @AlFonce I think I am going to go with **Mi-Creativity** idea.

Answer (score 16):

You can achieve this using "automated" SVG circle, automated because you don't need to hard code values like width, height, radius or viewBox dimensions, all it needs that the corresponding `img` tag has `width` and `height` attributes, also `stroke-width` attribute for the svg `circle`.

All further calculations depend on values of these attributes, like positioning both the image and the circle, setting width and height for the svg, also the values of radius and circumference of the circle. also if you have more than one circle in your page, circles don't need to have same width and size, each circle will take dimensions from the corresponding `img`.

All magic is in this line:

```
'stroke-dasharray': SVG.circum * ratio / 100 + ' ' + SVG.circum
```

Where `circum` is the length of the circle circumference, the concept behind this is controlling the values of **`stroke-dasharray`<sup>(1)</sup>** with our script. for example, suppose you call the function providing value of **`70`**, and let's say the `circum` is **`500`**, so it'll be:

```
stroke-dasharray: 350 500
```

think of it like the second value "`500`" is the full circle, the first value "`350`" is where the stroke stops.

To set values of a certain circle, just call the `miProgressbar()` function, passing the circle element and the needed value, like this:

```
miProgressbar($('#circle1'), 70);
```

> **Updated:** All examples below tested with Chrome, Firefox, IE9-IE11 and Vivaldi browsers, and worked in all *even* in IE9+, except that in IE9-IE11 example5 and example6 only the first circles have strokes, *not sure about modern versions of Safari, Opera and Edge*.

**Example 1: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/wWQPpw)** - *full circle* [ *`ratio = 100%`* ]

```js
var svgCircles = $('.wrapper svg circle');

miProgressbar($('#circle1'), 70);

// from here on, everything works automatically, you don't need to change anything
svgCircles.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $parent = $this.parent(),
    SVG = miSVGdata($this);

  $this.attr('r', SVG.radius);
  $parent.css({
    'top': SVG.strokeWidth / 2,
    'left': SVG.strokeWidth / 2
  });
  $parent.attr('viewBox', '0 0 ' + SVG.svgWidth + ' ' + SVG.svgHeight);
  $parent.attr('width', SVG.svgWidth);
  $parent.attr('height', SVG.svgHeight);
});

function miProgressbar(element, ratio) {
  var SVG = miSVGdata(element);
  element.css({
    'stroke-dasharray': SVG.circum * ratio / 100 + ' ' + SVG.circum
  });
}

function miSVGdata(element) {
  var svgParent = element.parent(),
    strokeWidth = parseInt(element.attr('stroke-width'), 10),
    img = element.parents('.wrapper').find('img'),
    svgWidth = parseInt(img.attr('width'), 10) + strokeWidth,
    svgHeight = parseInt(img.attr('height'), 10) + strokeWidth,
    circum, radius, svgObj;

  img.css({
    top: strokeWidth,
    left: strokeWidth
  });
  radius = svgWidth / 2 - strokeWidth / 2;
  circum = parseInt(2 * radius * 3.14, 10);
  svgObj = {
    svgWidth: svgWidth,
    svgHeight: svgHeight,
    parent: svgParent,
    strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
    radius: radius,
    circum: circum
  };
  return svgObj;
}
```

**HTML:**

The structure of the wrapper div will look like this, remember that *ALL* automated calculations are based on the `width` and `height` attribute of *each* image so they *must* be provided for these images.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="holder.js/150x150" width="150" height="150" class="img-circle img-thumbnail" />
  <svg class="mi-progressbar">
    <circle id="circle1" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-width="20"></circle>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that you can even inject the SVG code via javascript using `.insertAfter()` and this way your hardcoded wrapper would have the `img` only.

---

**Example 2: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/full/rLQYmr/)** - *coloring*

Example with multiple images and different styles with same colors as the bootstrap progress bar and same naming style, like this:

```
svg circle.progress-bar-success{ stroke:#5cb85c; }
```

---

**Example 3: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/full/ZOmapp/)** *with different values set when calling the function like this*:

```
miProgressbar($('#circle1'), 0);
miProgressbar($('#circle2'), 100);
miProgressbar($('#circle3'), 65);
miProgressbar($('#circle4'), 40);
miProgressbar($('#circle5'), 15);
```

---

**Example 4: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/full/KrAqjW/)** - *animating*

You can animate the circular progress bar by passing different -i.e increasing - ratio values to the `miProgressbar(element, ratio)` function. the code snippet for the above animation:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    if(i <= 100){
        miProgressbar(svgCircles, i);
        i++;
    }
}, 50);
```

---

**Example 5: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/full/akQEkR/)** - *different image sizes the svg circle will adapt it automatically by just changing values of `width` and `height` attributes of the `img`*.

<sub>* didn't work as supposed in IE9 - IE11, only first circle</sub>

---

**Example 6: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/full/kXQvax/)** - *value of `stroke-width` controls width of the border*

<sub>* didn't work as supposed in IE9 - IE11, only first circle</sub>

### --------------------------------------------

<sup>(1)</sup> - sources:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dasharray/
- [Lea Verou - The Missing Slice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4HdeJctq-A) **`35:50`-`42:10`**

Comment: I was gonna attempt to solve this but no way I can top this. Great answer !

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure your attempt would turn to be like this if not better even :)

Comment: Thank you for all this you will most likely get bounty will let it run for next couple of days to give people a chance.

Comment: You welcome and sure that's very fair, keep the bounty thing as you like, personally it wasn't much about the bounty rather than I took the question as a little challenge and I enjoyed it, thank you and have a good time