# I want to make a circle graph how to make it in javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a gryph like this: http://www.boerse.sx/3167643-post2.html. How do I have to design and programm it in javascript/html/css (it is for a mobile)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Progress Circle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried too google it?
Check this out: https://www.freshdesignweb.com/css-jquery-graph-bar-pie-chart/

Scroll down the page to "Dash Board Chart"
[image]

Hope it's what your looking for =)

Comment: Your welcome as long as you don't forget to give me an up-vote =)

Comment: You're welcome as long as you use "you're" correctly.