# Making a blue score animated bar

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a circle score rating item in HTML, CSS (don't know their real name)
basically the blue bar around the circle goes up to the point of the number.

I would like the bar to go around as an animation when the page loads. Currently I use PHP to output the number however this means the bar has no animation.

Please see image

[image]

A simple way I was thinking this could be done, is if PHP has any build in function to output up to a number, for example instead of outputting 3 it went 1,2,3 which could make the animation.

Code :

```
<div id="quad_rating_circle">
    <div class="c100 p<?php echo $score; ?> medium custom center dark fill">
        <span><?php echo $score;  ?></span>
        <div class="slice">
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div class="fill"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have spent a good hour and haven't come up with anything, any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the rendered HTML and CSS for the score indicator?

Comment: try css animation.

Comment: I am assuming you are trying to load some js or css files and on each file load you want to increase the progress.

Answer (score 0):

This was basically already here:

[CSS Progress Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle)

You can easiley add an CSS animation and also work with CSS `content`

Like shown here:
https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/