# CSS - Knob cursor in pure CSS + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

After playing around with the jQuery Knob framework, I've realized that it was difficult to work with AngularJS dynamic values and decided to make my own arc/ knobs in pure CSS.

In the knob, I represent 3 values: minimum, maximum and current value, which should all be dynamic. The color of the knob changes when the value exceeds its range.

HTML:

```
<div class="{{getColor()}} arc arc_start"></div>
```

JS:

```
function getColor(){
if($scope.value > $scope.maximum){
  return "arc_danger";
}
if($scope.value < $scope.minimum){
  return "arc_gray";
}
return "arc_success";
}
```

Now, if the value is within the range, I want to illustrate it using a small knob cursor, similar to the one implemented in jQuery Knob.

This is the link to the plunkr, which illustrates what I want to achieve.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Zb8bVih4hireLwNS3bfc?p=preview

Comment: So you want to rewrite a whole JavaScript library using CSS, and you want someone to do it for you?

Comment: No. I'm looking for a css/ js way to illustrate a cursor on a knob, simply taking the jQuery Knob as an example of how it could potentially look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea, but I don't think you should fully discard using JQuery's knob without using its full capabilities. I've update your JQuery knob to be dynamic.

[plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/xg5QHKS4BEYNHdgNm67p?p=preview)

```
$('.knob').on("input", function() {
      $scope.value = $('#value').val();
      $scope.minimum = $('#min').val();
      $scope.maximum = $('#max').val();
      $('.dial').val($scope.value);
      $('.dial').trigger('change');
      $('.dial').trigger('configure', {'min': $scope.minimum,'max':$scope.maximum,'fgColor':getColor()}); 
});
```

I'm not sure if using two divs on top of each other is the answer. If you really cannot use its functionality for your needs, perhaps look into using a progress bar shaped in a circle.

[SO question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle)

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Aapn8/3410/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The "CSS Progress Circle" question was a great redirect. I used the accepted answer from there to implement a CSS based progress circle. Thanks for the multiple alternatives and transparency in your answer.