# How to make border with percentage bar

Tags: html, css, image, border

I don't even know how to describe it really, so here's the picture.
[Yeah, something like that.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QFtQ.png) I mean the round border, but like only a part of it is red. Also, I don't want it to be animated or anything, so is it possible to make it only with CSS and HTML, with no JavaScript?
Would love to get some help here!

Comment: This answer seems to cover what you're after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can help you.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body{
    background:yellow;
    }
    .image{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    border:10px solid red;
    border-left:10px solid transparent;
    padding:15px;
    transform:rotate(45deg);
    }
    img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="image" >
    <img src="img.jpg" />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And you can also add :after and :before to add more border.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly!