# circular progress bar for 4 steps of form

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, pure-css

Looked for circular progress to indicate on which step the user is out of 4.

Like
1st form out of 4,
2nd form out of 4,
3rd form out of 4,
4th form out of 4

Below are screen shot of what is expected.

[image]

I got few example which had two div inside it. [CSS Progress Circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle)

Which I though was complex in my case where I just need 4 steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution which just used border and sudo elements `before` and `after`

Which is very simple.

**NOTE:** This can only used in case of 4 steps.

```css
.count {
     position: relative;
     width: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     display: inline-block;
     border: 1px solid #ffc107;
     border-radius: 50%;
     font-family: Arial;
     color: #888;
}
 .count span {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     z-index: 2;
}
 .count:after {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     background: #fff;
     width: 30px;
     height: 30px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     left: 5px;
     top: 5px;
}
 .count:before {
     position: absolute;
     content: "";
     border: 20px solid #ffc107;
     border-radius: 50%;
     height: 0;
     width: 0;
     transform: rotate(45deg);
}
 .count.step1:before {
     border-left-color: transparent;
     border-bottom-color: transparent;
     border-right-color: transparent;
}
 .count.step2:before {
     border-left-color: transparent;
     border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
 .count.step3:before {
     border-left-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="count step1">
  <span>1</span>
</div>
<div class="count step2">
  <span>2</span>
</div>
<div class="count step3">
  <span>3</span>
</div>
<div class="count">
  <span>4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the progress bar as a pseudo element to the form itself or of course as a separate element, using conic and radial gradients to draw the circle.

For example when you want to show when at a particular step of a totalSteps this could be drawn with:

```
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%), conic-gradient(gold 0 calc(360deg * var(--n) / var(--totalSteps)), transparent calc(360deg * var(--n) / var(--totalSteps)) 100%);
```

That way it will work for any number of steps.

Simple example:

```css
form.progress::after {
  /* these variables would be set by JS - they are here just for demo */
  --totalSteps: 4;
  --step: 3;
  --stepString: '3';
  content: var(--stepString);
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid gold;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 0 50%, transparent 50% 100%), conic-gradient(gold 0 calc(360deg * var(--step) / var(--totalSteps)), transparent calc(360deg * var(--step) / var(--totalSteps)) 360deg);
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="progress">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea using border:

```css
.step {
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:2px solid red;
  display:inline-grid;
  place-items:center;
  font-size:30px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.step:before {
  content:attr(data-step);
}
.step:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  inset:0;
  z-index:-1;
  border:14px solid;
  border-radius:50%;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
[data-step="1"]:after {border-color:red #0000 #0000 #0000}
[data-step="2"]:after {border-color:red red   #0000 #0000}
[data-step="3"]:after {border-color:red red   red   #0000}
[data-step="4"]:after {border-color:red red   red   red  }
```

```html
<div class="step" data-step="1"></div>
<div class="step" data-step="2"></div>
<div class="step" data-step="3"></div>
<div class="step" data-step="4"></div>
```