# Is there a way to rotate a CSS element with a ::before pseudo class to display a linear-gradient that rotates from 0 degrees to 360 degrees?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, linear-gradients

### Problem Definition

I have a div tag that has a border-radius of 50% to display a circle. Here is the HTML code below:

```css
.pie-wrapper {
  height: 2.5em;
  width: 2.5em;
  margin: 15px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.pie-wrapper--solid {
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pie-wrapper--solid:before {
  border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0 / 50%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform-origin: left;
}

.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-88 {
  border: 5px ridge blue;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, springgreen 50%, #ff0000 50%);
}

.pie-wrapper--solid.progress-88:before {
  background: springgreen;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  animation-name: change-color;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: normal;
}


/* Keyframes */

@keyframes change-color {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pie-wrapper pie-wrapper--solid progress-88">
</div>
```

### What I Tried

I applied a linear-gradient to create a background with two colors. I went ahead to try different **linear-gradient** types such as *to left*, *to bottom*, *to top* etc. This didn't achieve the purpose.

### The Expectation

The animation rotates to 180 degrees as expected but any number above **rotate(180deg)** will not cover the expected portions of the pie. The goal is for the red part to fully cover the green part in the animation keyframes at **rotate(360deg)** i.e a complete red circle. I would also like the animation to rotate anti-clockwise, this can be achieved by placing a negative value inside the rotate function.

Comment: [Maybe this question helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222138/css-progress-circle)

Comment: @Apodemus The problem is not the rotation itself but the ::before pseudo-class that does not rotate past 180 degrees.

Comment: To test what I'm trying to ask, remove the animation and change the value of transform: rotate(0deg) on the .pie-wrapper--solid.progress-88:before selector and use 90deg, 180deg, 270deg, and 360deg while viewing the output on each interval.